# ProcessBuilder gets stuck after getting an error

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a .bat file remotely and implementing following lines of code:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    final Process process = processBuilder.start();

    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Waiting ...");

    System.out.println("Returned Value :" + process.exitValue());
```

but my program gets stuck inside while loop.
The error it displays is:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

It never goes out of while loop.But it executes the script successfully.
Any sort of help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you're also dealing with stderr, and you should be dealing with both streams in separate threads.

Read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1) and make sure you follow **all** the advice.

Edit: Looking at the code you've written, you seem to have reproduced code from this precise article. In fact, it looks like listing 4.3 (MediocreExecJavac.java).

Comment: Alternatively, call `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` to redirect the process' standard error into its standard output.  Then you only need to read from `process.getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 2):

Add redirectErrorStream(true) before you .start() and read getInputStream().  This will read stderr and merge that with stdout into one response which can be read with getInputStream().

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    final Process process = processBuilder.start();

    InputStream stderr = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Waiting ...");

    System.out.println("Returned Value :" + process.exitValue());
```