# Java - batch file execution in ProcessBuilder gets blocked

Tags: jakarta-ee

Thanks for ur support.

I am executing a batch file from java using ProcessBuilder. This execution will be continued in a thread for every 4 min. The output and error will get, write to file.

This is working fine for 1 or 2 days. After that, executing thread gets blocked. I will restart the application and it work fine for another 1 or 2 days. I am with this problem again and again for last 20 days.

I tried analyzing. I didn't find any error from error stream. Everything is right upto the last  statement printed in log file. I took the thread dump and analyzed. Thread status

"load-thr" prio=6 tid=0x0000000009875000 nid=0x1014 runnable [0x000000000c71e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 - locked <0x00000000894fbeb8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.qqq.load(MyLoad.java:553) ==> this is the line of while() statement

Why its waiting in the while() statement line indefinitely?

What causes this lock?

```
public void load()
{       
    BufferedReader br1=null,br2=null;
    String err=null,err1=null;
    Process p=null;   
    try
    {
              ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder();
              pb.directory("my work directory given");
              pb.command("cmd.exe","/c","www.bat");
              pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
              p=pb.start();                                                           
              br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
              br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
              while((err=br1.readLine())!=null || (err1=br2.readLine())!=null) {  if(err!=null) {logtofile(err);} if(err1!=null) {logtofile(err1);}}
              p.waitFor();                                                            
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    finally
    {
        try{
            if(p!=null){p.destroy();}
            if(br1!=null) {br1.close();}
            if(br2!=null) {br2.close();}                
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}

public void logtofile(String err){
    //all statements are written to file.
    //file 'll be changed over the time when file size exceeds 2MB.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807834/processbuilder-gets-stuck-after-getting-an-error)
. Basically you should read your streams in another thread(s). Because reading from a stream is blocking call until some input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.